# Can someone explain the algorithm of this java program?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I found it in the net and I want to know the explanation of it's algorithm.
I'm having a hard time to understand this. thank you so much :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class BinarySearch 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int c, first, last, middle, n, search, array[];

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of elements");
n = in.nextInt(); 
array = new int[n];

System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");


for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
  array[c] = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter value to find");
search = in.nextInt();

first  = 0;
last   = n - 1;
middle = (first + last)/2;

while( first <= last )
{
  if ( array[middle] < search )
    first = middle + 1;    
  else if ( array[middle] == search ) 
  {
    System.out.println(search + " found at location " + (middle + 1) + ".");
    break;
  }
  else
     last = middle - 1;

  middle = (first + last)/2;
 }
 if ( first > last )
  System.out.println(search + " is not present in the list.\n");
  }
 }
```

I'll appreciate your response. thanks again.

Comment: It's a binary search program, why don't you run it and see for your self what it does.

Comment: It's 2016 and there are still code examples where the user is asked how many entries will be provided and an array is instantiated to hold them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The binary search algorithm begins by comparing the target value to the value of the middle element of the sorted array. If the target value is equal to the middle element's value, then the position is returned and the search is finished. If the target value is less than the middle element's value, then the search continues on the lower half of the array; or if the target value is greater than the middle element's value, then the search continues on the upper half of the array. This process continues, eliminating half of the elements, and comparing the target value to the value of the middle element of the remaining elements - until the target value is either found (and its associated element position is returned), or until the entire array has been searched (and "not found" is returned).

Here is your answer beautifully explained :

check this out 
http://www.csit.parkland.edu/~mbrandyberry/CS1Java/Lessons/Lesson27/BinarySearch.htm

Comment: it will help me alot. thank you for your good response :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: wut do you mean? @Kyll